# How to Displays the maximum number in the string type column in the table using MySQL SUBSTRING

Tags: php, mysql

My column name is "momor_request" and my data is :

- 1000/REPORT/2022
- 999/REPORT/2022

If iám using SQL Query :

```sql
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nomor_request,'/',1)) AS max_number FROM my_table
```

It will show :
999

How to display the max value is (1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the numeric substring to an integer and then find the max:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nomor_request, '/', 1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS max_number
FROM my_table;
```

The reason that your current query is showing `999` as being larger than `1000` is that, when sorted as text, `1000` comes *before* `999`, as the latter starts with `1`.

Comment: Perpect, thank you ! you solved my case